# restrict directory listing linux

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to restrict access to certain directories to my ssh users but allow them to read files by known path from there(mostly it's meant to be done by applications). How is that possible? Are there easy ways? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't be enough to `chmod -r /certain/directories`?

Answer (score -1):

Directories have to have +x permissions in order of someone to read files from within via exact path.

Comment: This is wrong. Without the `x`-permission you cannot access files in the directory. (Well, I find the things happening w/o the exec permission kind of strange, but…) Listing files, as the OP asked, requires the `r`-permission.